Adding serialize class to list using custom Inspector
So Im trying to added to my list behaviours,
I want to click the Behaviour I want to added and to show in inspector the right Behaviour Class and his properties.
Right now I can add a behaviour to the list but it shows as this :
.
.
Is there a way for me to see the class propertied to be able to modify it?
This is my Behaviours classes:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class BehaviourBase 
{
    public virtual void ExecuteBehaviour(ObjectInLevel objectInLevel)
    {
        Debug.Log("Executing Base Behaviour");
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class DiminishingReturnBehaviour : BehaviourBase
{
    [Tooltip("Amount that will decrease from the hope point per click till reaches 0")]
    public int DiminishingReturnReduceAmount;


    public override void ExecuteBehaviour(ObjectInLevel objectInLevel)
    {
        Debug.Log("Executing Diminishing Return ");
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class MindCuesBehaviour : BehaviourBase
{
    public List<MindCues> MindCues;


    public override void ExecuteBehaviour(ObjectInLevel objectInLevel)
    {
        Debug.Log("Executing Mind Cue ");
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class DisappearBehaviour : BehaviourBase
{
    [Tooltip("If this object have unique animation, insert the anim name/param, else leave empty")] public string animName;
    [Tooltip("If this object have unique sprite switches, insert the sprite, else leave empty")] public Sprite _sprite;


    public override void ExecuteBehaviour(ObjectInLevel objectInLevel)
    {
        Debug.Log("Executing Disappear ");
    }
}

And my Editor Script :
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ObjectData))]
public class ObjectDataEditor : Editor
{
    private ObjectData objectData;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        objectData = (ObjectData)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        DrawDefaultInspector();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add Behaviour"))
        {
            GenericMenu menu = new GenericMenu();

            menu.AddItem(new GUIContent("DiminishingReturnBehaviour"), false, () => AddBehaviour(typeof(DiminishingReturnBehaviour)));
            menu.AddItem(new GUIContent("MindCuesBehaviour"), false, () => AddBehaviour(typeof(MindCuesBehaviour)));
            menu.AddItem(new GUIContent("DisappearBehaviour"), false, () => AddBehaviour(typeof(DisappearBehaviour)));

            menu.ShowAsContext();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < objectData.Behaviours.Count; i++)
        {
            var behaviour = objectData.Behaviours[i];
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField(behaviour.GetType().Name, EditorStyles.boldLabel);

            if (GUILayout.Button("Remove"))
            {
                objectData.Behaviours.RemoveAt(i);
            }

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
            SerializedProperty behaviourProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("Behaviours").GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(behaviourProperty, true);
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }
            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void AddBehaviour(System.Type type)
    {
        BehaviourBase behaviour = (BehaviourBase)System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        objectData.Behaviours.Add(behaviour);
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
    }
}

The list of the behaviours at my ObjectData - and its Scriptable Object.
public List Behaviours = new List();
I did try to add Property Drawer but it doesn't seem to work. Or maybe I just dont know if its the right way to go

AFAIR you need editors for all your behaviors.

The problem I guess its with the way Im adding Base class to the list. its nothing to do with the Inspector editor I guess.

Ok so in my case, the problem was that my List didnt have [SerializeReference] on top of it.
I read about it from the doc :
"You want to use polymorphism on fields whose type is a custom serializable class.
If you try to use polymorphism on custom serializable classes without the [SerializeReference] attribute, your derived classes' additional fields won't be preserved, and your object will instead be serialized as if it was the field's declared type. You can see polymorphism in the SerializeReferencePolymorphismExample class below."

